# Display HTML input number Live Under input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have One Input For Price And i want to showing Live typing price under input field
like this :

[http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T4mX6/1/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

but i treid to seperate price with comma On display
so while typing price it shows price with comma under input field

i have this loan calculator [https://codepen.io/thcweb/pen/PoBmKbm](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
but i cant price with comma input text without calculate problem

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The code relevant to your problem belongs _directly_ into your question, not just the whole thing dumped onto an external platform like jsfiddle or codepen. (Also, you did not even manage to _link_ to either of those correctly.)

Comment: Plus, your fiddle doesn't contain anything of what you said you tried. You need to _show us_ what you tried, and give a proper problem description along with it - and not just _tell_ us, that you tried something.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.